# boot old computer from ethernet with laptop as server

Tags: networking, boot, operating-systems

I have an old computer. It currently cannot boot from CD/dvd its drive is (I think broken). I want to boot an operating system into it- the only option seems to be ethernet. I have a laptop which is functioning correctly. I want to use it as the server and boot (an ISO that I have on the laptop)on the computer. How to accomplish this? Is there any way or any other method to boot? USB not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would probably help to know what operating system the laptop / server is running. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if the BIOS of the old computer supports
[Preboot eXecution Environment (PXE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)
as PXE client.

Since you don't have an operating system on the old computer, if it
supports PXE then on boot the BIOS will automatically search as a
last resort for a PXE server on the network (Ethernet only).

If you don't see it searching for the PXE server, then the computer
doesn't support PXE. You could also search its BIOS for a PXE
option that you can enable (if one exists).

If you do see it, you will need to setup the laptop as a PXE server,
which needs some technical ability.

For more information see the article
[preboot execution environment (PXE)](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/Preboot-Execution-Environment).

Comment: PXE is often done by an Option ROM of the network card rather than by the BIOS itself, so in case the built-in NIC doesn't support it, it should be possible to eBay a PCI Ethernet card that does. (For old computers, I *think* Intel PRO/1000 MT always has PXE support?)

Comment: @user1686: Wikipedia says "is implemented either as a Network Interface Card (NIC) *BIOS extension* or current devices in *UEFI code*".

Comment: Yeah, and the Option ROM is a "BIOS extension" since it's found and executed by the BIOS, but it still comes from the card itself. It can't add setup menu items, though, so addon cards will usually show a custom "press foo to configure" prompt instead. (I'm not sure how it works with pure UEFI, but an old PC like OP's will most likely have CSM or just BIOS.)